# What is difference between cloneDatabase and copyDatabase mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

The documentation says:

db.cloneDatabase("hostname")

- Copies a remote database to the current database. The command assumes that the remote database has the same name as the current database.

This method provides a wrapper around the MongoDB database command “clone.” The [copydb](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/command/copydb/#dbcmd.copydb) database command provides related functionality.

I don't see big difference between the commands.
Please, could someone explain me if one is faster than other or when choose each one?
Tks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You do not see many differences, because they do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Please explain better your answer

Answer (score 0):

`cloneDB` and `copyDB` do the same job but there is slightly difference as I observed. Listed below:

**copyDB**

- can copy from same/different mongod.
- can save in destination as different name than original name
- you can copy from primary/secondary server.
- relatively no-lock during operation.

**cloneDB**

- Not possible to clone the db in same instance.
- Destination DB name will be same as the source
- you cannot use primary server to clone database
- it does lock during the process